# opening selected tab in list of menu using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have a list this way. And in my home page i have three option candiatesignup, assessor signup and employer signup.now when i click from assessor want to make assessor selected. How to do it dynamically using angular js.
I tried `ng-class`

```
 <li><a ng-class="{selected: activeTab == 'cd-candidate'}" href="#cd-candidate">Candidate Sign up</a></li>
```

this is without ng-class:

```
 <ul class="cd-switcher">
  <li><a class="selected" href="#cd-candidate">Candidate Sign up</a></li>
  <li><a href="#cd-assessor">Assessor Sign up</a></li>
 <li><a href="#cd-employer">Employer Sign up</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the tab value in click and apply css class using `ng-class` conditional approach

Try Below, You might not need the CSS.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('TabCtrl', function() {
    this.tab = 1;
    //Set selected Tab
    this.setTab = function(tabId) {
      this.tab = tabId;
    };
    //Get Selected
    this.getTab = function(tabId) {
      return this.tab === tabId;
    };
  });
})();
```

```css
.nav>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.nav>li.selected>a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TabCtrl as tab">
    <ul class="nav">

      <li ng-class="{selected:tab.getTab(1)}"><a href="#cd-candidate" ng-click="tab.setTab(1)">Candidate Sign up</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{selected:tab.getTab(2)}"><a href="#cd-assessor" ng-click="tab.setTab(2)">Assessor Sign up</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{selected:tab.getTab(3)}"><a href="#cd-candidate" ng-click="tab.setTab(3)">Employer Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```